# purpose of Microsofts FETCH loop example?

Tags: t-sql

I see this example in Microsofts documentation

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;  
GO  
DECLARE contact_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT LastName FROM Person.Person  
WHERE LastName LIKE 'B%'  
ORDER BY LastName;  

OPEN contact_cursor;  

-- Perform the first fetch.  
FETCH NEXT FROM contact_cursor;  

-- Check @@FETCH_STATUS to see if there are any more rows to fetch.  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
   -- **This is executed as long as the previous fetch succeeds.**  
   FETCH NEXT FROM contact_cursor;  
END  

CLOSE contact_cursor;  
DEALLOCATE contact_cursor;  
GO
```

I'm wondering and asking

a) what happens inside the FETCH-WHILE loop? It seems to do just nothing, except skipping over the comment. Can one possibly do something on the data, without using `'INTO'`?

b) how to access the column data from the current row, inside the loop, in T-SQL? Preferrably just `contact_cursor.LastName` .

Yes I read that I should work 'set-based', and cursors are not efficient. But I'm allowed to do processing (string manips, testing them, and in the end one UPDATE per row) in T-SQL and not in the outside procedural environment, and do it carefully in a robust way, and it is just a couple of records, once+testing. And me perfectly new to T-SQL, but old to SQL and many other things. T-SQL is 2016 when it matters.

Plz I can't reply as comments, because my level is too low. I'm grateful for help, for the explanation of this. Thank you!

Comment: From the LMGTFY Department, have a look [here](http://stevestedman.com/2013/04/t-sql-a-simple-example-using-a-cursor/) or [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/sql-server-cursor-example/). In short, Microsoft has provided a do-nothing example that doesn't help.

Comment: Yes, this is a poor example from Microsoft.  They should have shown it doing *something* with the data within the loop.  @HABO 's link has a better example.

Comment: also, as far as I know, you can *always* reply to comments in your own post/thread.

Comment: both examples by HABO use the FETCH NEXT INTO .. variant. But from what I learned, one can do UPDATE .. WHERE CURRENT ..., or DELETE. The issue with me is that I need to access one column, do a long-winded string calculation on it, and then update the column. It seems I need INTO anyway.

Comment: It's not really a variant.  It's how you access and use the individual column values returned by the FETCH statement.

Comment: By the way, the comment from Microsoft in its example  "-- Check @@FETCH_STATUS to see if there are any more rows to fetch." is wrong. It should read "Check @@FETCH_STATUS to see if a row was fetched ." ...

Answer (score 0):

contact_cursor in this example is an ordered collection of column values that make up a row from the select statement.

In this case just LastName.

If you want to do anything with the values you need to fetch them into an ordered list of variables.  See the example just below the one you copied into your question on this page:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/fetch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

To do something with the fetched values you need to remember you came into the loop with the first value already fetched.  So you'll place any work done with here:

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

-- **Do work with previously fetched value(s) here ** 

--  **Fetch next  
FETCH NEXT FROM contact_cursor;  
END
```

You should notice a small hole in the logic here.  What if there is no next?  You'll need to also do operations on the last fetch value outside of the loop.

Alternatively:

```
-- ** Do work on first fetched value
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

FETCH NEXT FROM contact_cursor;
-- ** Do work on next fetched  
END
```

Anything you can do with a simple variable, you can do with the fetched values inside your loop.

Best Alternative as suggested by Peter in comments:

```
WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN  

FETCH NEXT FROM contact_cursor;

-- ** Do work on next fetched 

IF ( @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0)
    BREAK;
END
```

Comment: The first value is fetched with the first FETCH NEXT, outside the loop. And the other FETCH NEXT has to be the last statement in the loop. This is standard serial processing since the days of Jackson (Principles of Program Design, 1975) The alternative is not working, there another "if @@FETCH_STATUS = 0" after FETCH NEXT is required.

Comment: The first value is fetched here:  OPEN contact_cursor; FETCH NEXT FROM contact_cursor;  I did not copy anything from OP's post before the loop began.  You fetch the first before the loop.  So you either need to act upon it before the loop(the alternate listed last in the answer) OR act upon it inside the loop, and act on the last fetched value after the loop ends.  FETCH NEXT does not need to be the last command in the loop, they are two distinctly separate entities.  The "if Fetch_status" is the loop condition.  But if you got the first one to work for you, use that one.

Comment: ok I got it . Standard processing is: OPEN, FETCH NEXT, while(@@FETCH_STATUS=0) BEGIN .. do processing .. FETCH NEXT END CLOSE . That is we need two FETCH, one FETCH-STATUS. The alternative is two FETCH-STATUS and one FETCH. Coding the processing twice leads to trouble. The standard scheme works on any data stream. "Jackson" handles to case when there are streams with different periodicity, that is one needs to turn inside-out such loops with the aid of status variables. -- But my primary question was: can I get at a column without INTO (answer до сех пор: no).

Comment: I agree that  with FETCH.. INTO variables it is preferable to have just one FETCH statement. However this requires, in theory: WHILE (1=1) BEGIN FETCH NEXT INTO variables if @@FETCH_STATUS<>0 BREAK process END. This makes for one FETCH, one @@FETCH_STATUS and a WHILE+BREAK.

Comment: @Peter Oh, hahaha.  I missed it yesterday, but I see what you did now.  That's a great idea.